# NSFileHandle updateatPath how can i update file instead of overwriting?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilehandle

I am trying to create a file and update the file by adding a string to the end each time i hit save button. However, everytime i hit save it creates a new file (overwrites) with the latest string. My code is below, how can i fix it? please help!

```
func pathToDocsFolder() -> String {

    let pathToDocumentsFolder =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

    return pathToDocumentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/log.csv")
}  

@IBAction func saveSample(sender: AnyObject) {

    let string = LabelText + ";" + SampleNoOne.text! + ";" + fromOne.text! + ";" + toOne.text! + ";" + casingBlowsOne.text! + ";"

    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()


    if filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(pathToDocsFolder()){
        filemanager.createFileAtPath(pathToDocsFolder(), contents: data, attributes: nil)
    }


    let fileHandle = NSFileHandle.init(forUpdatingAtPath: pathToDocsFolder())

    fileHandle!.seekToEndOfFile()
    fileHandle!.writeData(data)
    fileHandle!.closeFile()
```

Comment: Why do you create the file if it exists? I think you mean to only create the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

update:

```
if filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(pathToDocsFolder()){
     filemanager.createFileAtPath(pathToDocsFolder(), contents: data, attributes: nil)
}
```

to:

```
if filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(pathToDocsFolder()) == false {
        filemanager.createFileAtPath(pathToDocsFolder(), contents: data, attributes: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to append in the file use "forWritingAtPath" instead of "forUpdatingAtPath"
Replace the following line:

```
let fileHandle = NSFileHandle.init(forUpdatingAtPath: pathToDocsFolder())
```

With

```
let fileHandle = NSFileHandle.init(forWritingAtPath: pathToDocsFolder())
```

Also make sure your condition to check existing file is correct.